# Passing on optional parameters in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters, option-type

I understand that I can set up a PHP function to accept optional parameters.

However if I am writing my function as a wrapper for another function which itself takes optional parameters, I don't know if there is a slick-and-easy way to do this.

I am considering writing clunky code like:

```
function doBindValue__($stmtEE, $placeholder, $value, $type = NULL)
{
     /**
      * Now IN FACT the interface to bindValue is specified to use PDO::PARAM_STR as the default
      *  so I could use it as MY default above, 
      *  but that feels like cluncky assuming-too-much
      *  since I don't own that specification and it could change later ( I suppose ).
      */

    $GLOBALS[ "PDOFailedOperation" ] = "bindValue";

    if (is_null($type))
    {
        $stmtEE->bindValue($placeholder, $value);
    }
    else
    {
        $stmtEE->bindValue($placeholder, $value, $type);
    }
}
```

If I knew that passing a NULL as a parameter was EXACTLY THE SAME as passing a missing parameter, it would be easy enough, but I haven't found that written down anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried php's [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)? this doesn't seem to pull in $placeholder=null parameters.

Comment: thanks mfink - that seems to do it, but it isn't exactly pretty :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `func_get_args` and `call_user_func_array` PHP functions.

For help about functions see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Your snippet can be rewrited using those functions as follows:

```
function doBindValue__($stmtEE, $placeholder, $value, $type = NULL)
{

    $GLOBALS[ "PDOFailedOperation" ] = "bindValue";

    return call_user_func_array(array($stmtEE, 'bindValue'), func_get_args());
}
```

For php 5.3 or above

Comment: Thank you for that - how very non-obvious that looks on the page :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that if I ensure that the version of PHP I am using is 5.6 or better, I can do this very simply using the new .... token.

Since I am in a position to force that upgrade on our servers, I think I'll go that way.